# Yii2 - Change password user afterLogin

Tags: php, yii2

I have develope an application using yii2. Then I need to verify my user on afterLogin to change her/him password, coz in my User model is defined by default '123456'. 
If still 123456, i want make a modal bootstrap to notif my user to change password.

The code like this

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $model = new User();
    $model->scenario = 'create';

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->status = $model->status == 1 ? 10 : 0;
        $model->setPassword('123456');
        ....
}
```

So, in config/web.php just like this :

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'on afterLogin' =>  ['app\events\AfterLoginEvent', 'handlePasswordForFirstTime'],
        // 'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
```

In events, just like this :

```
namespace app\events;
use Yii;
use app\models\User;

class AfterLoginEvent{
public static function handlePasswordForFirstTime($event){
    $user = new User();
    /*How to check if password still 123456*/
   }
}
```

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

Just validate password

```
if ($user || $user->validatePassword('123456')) {
    // password is still '123456'
} else {
    // user has changed password
}
```

Comment: Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
Hash is invalid.